# Using Variables Inside of Cookie Reg Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies, session-cookies

Im trying to add a variable into a reg expression. I believe its called backreference but cannot seem to figure out how to create a string+variable to search for that cookie. I tried making it a template literal and adding a string within.

I've been referencing this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression) and have attempted many solutions but am struggling to get this to work properly. 
I've tried replacing it with `replaceAll("searchCookie", 'searchCookie${this.type}')`

Backstory: I have a function that will create the base searchCookie + this.type inside my checkCookie function I run this command to get the cookie if it exists or not. Let me know if any details are missed and i appreciate the advice/help

`cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*searchCookie+Variable\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var x="abcd"
cookie.match('/^(.*;)?\s*'+ x +'\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/')
```

Comment: While your code may answer the PO's question, you should add a brief explanation of what you have done and how that solves the problem.